# Why java classes do not inherit annotations from implemented interfaces?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, annotations

I'm using a Dependency Injection framework (Guice's AOP to intercept some method calls specifically). My class implements an interface and I would like to annotate the interface methods so the framework could select the right methods. Even if the annotation type is annotated with [Inherited](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) annotation implementing class doesn't inherit the annotation as stated in Inherited's java doc:

> Note also that this meta-annotation
> only causes annotations to be
> inherited from superclasses;
> annotations on implemented interfaces
> have no effect.

What could be the reason for this? Getting to know all interfaces that an object's class does implement in runtime is not that hard thing to do so there must be a good reason behind this decision.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I'd say the reason is that otherwise a multiple-inheritance problem would occur.

**Example:**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD) @Inherited
public @interface Baz { String value(); }

public interface Foo{
    @Baz("baz") void doStuff();
}

public interface Bar{
    @Baz("phleem") void doStuff();
}

public class Flipp{
    @Baz("flopp") public void doStuff(){}
}

public class MyClass extends Flipp implements Foo, Bar{}
```

If I do this:

```
MyClass.class.getMethod("doStuff").getAnnotation(Baz.class).value()
```

what's the result going to be? 'baz', 'phleem' or 'flopp'?

---

For this reason, annotations on interfaces are rarely useful.

Comment: annotations on interfaces are only useful if you have a framework which supports them. BTW in this example getAnnotation() returns null ;)

Comment: I don't know, people. In this case (if the typo wasn't there), I'd expect a `The field value is ambiguous.`-like compiler error just like with two interfaces declaring the same constant with different values. I know that this is _not_ a field, but annotation values get all resolved at compile time, don't they? The feature we're missing here would be super-helpful in many cases. Sorry about reviving an old post, by the way :).

Comment: @Slanec have a look at the way the Spring sources to see how the Spring guys worked around these problems. See [AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, annotationType)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-core/3.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.java#AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation%28java.lang.reflect.Method%2Cjava.lang.Class%29)

Comment: I was considering writing something similar to this. With some sort of simple caching, this seems like a way to go for me. Thanks! In the example above, it would find the `Foo`'s annotation (`MyClass` doesn't have one, then Interfaces are searched and taken in the order in which they are after `implements`) and therefore print "baz". Cool.

Comment: Should that be `getAnnotation(Baz.class)`?

Comment: @WChargin true, it just took 2 years for someone to spot that typo :-)

Comment: Java 8 introduced `Repeatable` annotations, which means multiple annotations of the same type can be placed on a type. So, at least now, annotation inheritance from interfaces could be properly supported by Java.

Comment: @Katona true. But this question was actually in the Scope of Java 6 :-)

Answer (score 38):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) for @Inherited:

> Indicates that an annotation type is automatically inherited. If an
>   Inherited meta-annotation is present on an annotation type
>   declaration, and the user queries the annotation type on a class
>   declaration, and the class declaration has no annotation for this
>   type, then the class's superclass will automatically be queried for
>   the annotation type. This process will be repeated until an annotation
>   for this type is found, or the top of the class hierarchy (Object) is
>   reached. If no superclass has an annotation for this type, then the
>   query will indicate that the class in question has no such annotation.
>   Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated
>   type is used to annotate anything other than a class. Note also that
>   this meta-annotation only causes annotations to be inherited from
>   superclasses; annotations on implemented interfaces have no effect.

On the other hand, JSR 305 validators do some sort of inheritance lookup. If you have a hierarchy of classes:

```
//Person.java
@Nonnull
 public Integer getAge() {...}

//Student.java (inherits from Person)
@Min(5)
public Integer getAge() {...}
```

Then the effective validations on `Student.getAge()` are `@Nonnull @Min(5)`. `@Nonnull` has no `@Inherited` meta-annotation.

Comment: This one should be the selected answer

Comment: your example contradict your answer, which says that `@Inherited` has no effect on anything other than class

Comment: @Inherited only work when you use the annotation on Class

Comment: What about answering OP's question about annotations on interfaces!?