# Is class extends annotations of an other?

Tags: java, annotations

I've a class Foo, which have an @Entity and @Table annotation, and an other class, Bar, which extends Foo.
Are the annotations on the Bar class? If not, can I force that?

Thanks a lot!
Sam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations are not inherited.

You can read more here: http://fusionsoft-online.com/articles-java-annotations.php

Some other references:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1644135/1001027
and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4745820/1001027

Exceptions are annotations which its declaration is annotated with [@Inherited](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html).

Comment: By _default_, annotations are not inherited.  However, annotations _are_ inherited (from superclasses) if they are meta-annotated with the `@Inherited` annotation.

Comment: @matts: you are right, annotations are inherited in case its declaration (annotation itself) is annotated with `@Inherited`.

Answer (score 1):

The `@Entity` and `@Table` annotations are not inherited by default, but you can use the `@Inheritance` annotation on the superclass to cause them to be inherited to subclasses, though.

See here for more information: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Check [@MappedSuperclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) annotation.

Comment: This is just valid for JPA, it has no meaning for pure java