# Annotation is not inherited from interface method

Tags: java, annotations

I have an interface with an annotated method. The annotation is marked with `@Inherited`, so I expect an implementor to inherit it. However, it is not the case:

Code:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {
        TestInterface obj = new TestInterface() {
            @Override
            public void m() {}
        };

        printMethodAnnotations(TestInterface.class.getMethod("m"));
        printMethodAnnotations(obj.getClass().getMethod("m"));
    }

    private static void printMethodAnnotations(Method m) {
        System.out.println(m + ": " + Arrays.toString(m.getAnnotations()));
    }
}

interface TestInterface {
    @TestAnnotation
    public void m();
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@interface TestAnnotation {}
```

The above code prints:

> public abstract void annotations.TestInterface.m(): [@annotations.TestAnnotation()]
>
> public void annotations.Example$1.m(): []

So the question is why does not the `obj.m()` have `@TestAnnotation` despite that it implements a method marked with `@TestAnnotation` which is `@Inherited`?

Comment: The answer was right there in the documentation of `@Inherited` as pointed out by @AbhinavSakar and @Gilberto. 
Sorry about that. I did quite a bit of experimentation but missed the obvious - the docs.

Comment: By the way, any idea on what is the reason for such a design decision? I would expect the meta-annotation to work on methods too.

Comment: No problem, it is surprising that super-classes are treated differently from super-interfaces. That's why some frameworks (such as Spring) ship with reflection utilities that also query the super interfaces.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which utility in Spring is that?

Comment: [`org.springframework.core.type.classreading.MetadataReader`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/type/classreading/MetadataReader.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why java classes do not inherit annotations from implemented interfaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745798/why-java-classes-do-not-inherit-annotations-from-implemented-interfaces)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) of `java.lang.annotation.Inherited`:

> Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated
>   type is used to annotate anything other than a class. Note also that
>   this meta-annotation only causes annotations to be inherited from
>   superclasses; annotations on implemented interfaces have no effect.

Comment: Woa, answered at same time =)

Comment: I upvoted both, but had to accept only one answer. Sorry, @Gilberto, Abhinav was a tiny bit quicker :)

Comment: No problem, we are here to help ;-)

Answer (score 23):

From the [@Inherited](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) javadoc:

> Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated type is used to annotate anything other than a class. Note also that this meta-annotation only causes annotations to be inherited from superclasses; annotations on implemented interfaces have no effect.`

In summary, it doesn't apply to methods.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use reflection to derive the same information. The method `printMethodAnnotations` can be rewritten as:

```
private static void printMethodAnnotations(Method m) {
    Class<?> methodDeclaredKlass = m.getDeclaringClass();
    List<Class<?>> interfases = org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils.getAllInterfaces(methodDeclaredKlass);
    List<Annotation> annotations = new ArrayList<>();
    annotations.addAll(Arrays.asList(m.getAnnotations()));
    for (Class<?> interfase : interfases) {
        for (Method interfaseMethod : interfase.getMethods()) {
            if (areMethodsEqual(interfaseMethod, m)) {
                annotations.addAll(Arrays.asList(interfaseMethod.getAnnotations()));
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(m + "*: " + annotations);
}

private static boolean areMethodsEqual(Method m1, Method m2) {
    // return type, Modifiers are not required to check, if they are not appropriate match then it will be a compile
    // time error. This needs enhancements for Generic types parameter ?
    return m1.getName().equals(m2.getName()) && Arrays.equals(m1.getParameterTypes(), m2.getParameterTypes());
}
```

Comment: thanks.. worked for me. But i could find same using spring core's AnnotationUtils. Here is maven dep