# Java annotation on interface method definition not being processed?

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj, spring-aop

I have the following code structure:

```
public interface InterfaceName {
    @AnnotationTwo
    public void method_name();  
} 

public class InterfaceNameImpl implements InterfaceName{
    @AnnotationOne
    public void method_name() {

    }
}
```

When I call method_name, `@AnnotationOne` is processed but `@AnnotationTwo` is not (judging by the logs)
Do I need to make some sort of configuration or something for `@AnnotationTwo` to be processed? (Also, the annotations' code is external, so I can't change that). Ideally, I want `@AnnotationTwo` to be processed before `@AnnotationOne`.

I have an aspectj join point around the execution of `@AnnotaionTwo` and the corresponding code is not being executed. However the aspectj code corresponding to joint point `@AnnotationOne` is executed. I want the code corresponding to `@AnnotationTwo` to be processed before the code corresponding to `@AnnotationOne`.

**Note:** I am using apsectj with load time weaving as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/setup.html#creating-project)

Comment: Did you check this about java annotations and method overriding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082619/how-do-java-method-annotations-work-in-conjunction-with-method-overriding?

Comment: @Vikdor That talks about the case when a class extends other class. I think that's different scenario that mine. Or is the behavior same?

Answer (score 2):

Not the freshest answer ever, but I believe it still holds:

Annotations on interface methods are not inherited when implementing said interface. 
[Annotation is not inherited from interface method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428858/annotation-is-not-inherited-from-interface-method)
[Why java classes do not inherit annotations from implemented interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745798/why-java-classes-do-not-inherit-annotations-from-implemented-interfaces)