# Interfaces, annotations inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations, overriding

I've a Java question about interfaces, annotations and 'inheritance' (let me use this 
word even if we're talking about interfaces).

Here's an example, then my question:

```
public interface A {

   @SomeKindOfAnnotation(..)
   boolean modifyElement(String id)
}

public class B implements A{

    @Override
    public boolean modifyElement(String id){

        //Implementation

    }
}
```

Can the method `modifyElement(String id)` (in the class B) inherit the annotation `@SomeKindOfAnnotation`? If yes how can I access the annotation value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745798/why-java-classes-do-not-inherit-annotations-from-implemented-interfaces

Comment: Great! I've not found this question before! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

public @interface SomeKindOfAnnotation{

```
public String typeOfSecurityNeeded();
```

}

---

public interface A {

```
@SomeKindOfAnnotation(typeOfSecurityNeeded = "low")
public void f3() ;
```

### }

public class B implements A {

```
@Override
public void f3() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

### }

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class TestProgram {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        A obj = new B();
        Class c = obj.getClass();
        Method m = c.getMethod("f3");

        if(m.isAnnotationPresent(SomeKindOfAnnotation.class))
        {
            SomeKindOfAnnotation x = m.getAnnotation(SomeKindOfAnnotation.class);
            System.out.println("level of  security is " +x.typeOfSecurityNeeded() );
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("no security ");
        }

    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

### }

O/P -------->>>>>>>>>

no security

---

now add annotation in class B

public class B implements A {

```
@Override
@SomeKindOfAnnotation(typeOfSecurityNeeded = "low")
public void f3() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

---

O/P ---->>>>>

level of  security is low