# Spring AOP inherited annotation from an interface

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop

I have an annotation:

```
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD } )
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )
@Inherited
public @interface Privilege {

    String[] value();   
}
```

And an interface:

```
public interface UserService {
    @Privilege("USER_READ")
    UserDTO getUserProperties(long userId);
}
```

and its implementation:

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
     public UserDTO getUserProperties(long userId) { ... }
}
```

And Spring AOP setting:

```
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <aop:config>
      <aop:aspect id="securityAspect" ref="hlSecurityCheck">
      <aop:pointcut id="securityPointcut" 
                    expression="@annotation(services.annotation.Privilege)" />
                <aop:around pointcut-ref="securityPointcut" method="checkService" />
...
```

Why this is not working? (It is working when I put the annotation directly on UserServiceImpl's method...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, annotations are not inhereted from interfaces. You should create an abstract super class to be able to do this. For more info have a look at [Why java classes do not inherit annotations from implemented interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745798/why-java-classes-do-not-inherit-annotations-from-implemented-interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

`@Inhereted` annotation can be inherited only by classed and interfaces themselves, not their methods. That is if you annotated `UserService` with `@Privilege` annotation then `UserServiceImpl` would inherited it.