# Spring PUT not mapping to method

Tags: java, spring

It's strange that my PUT operations is not mapped to spring method, I've following classes...

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = { "/**/applicationContext/abcde" })
public abstract class AbstractController { 
  // Exception handlers
}
```

This class is extended by another abstract class, as below

```
public abstract class AbstractAdapter extends AbstractController{}
```

Finally, above class is extended by below class

```
public class SpringAdapter extends AbstractAdapter implements MyInterface{}
```

And I've some put operations to be made which looks like below :-

```
@Override
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.PUT }, consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",     produces = "application/xml", params = {
        "param1=some_value", param2 })
public MyObject update(
        @RequestParam(value = param2, required = true) @ContentType(value = Encoding.XML)     MyObejct myObject, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{ }
```

But when I invoke put method then the request is not mapping to my update method.
Can anybody please help.

Comment: Do you really sure that your request contains all required options? `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers. The URL has `param1=some_value` and I guess that `param2` is a static const with in the similar `myParam=myValue` style.

Comment: I would also be curious to hear if your SpringAdapter actually uses the @Controller annotation. Otherwise it will not be scanned and therefor not be found

Comment: @Joeblade: Since my parent class has been marked with Controller annotation and hence I do not need to mark my SpringAdapter with Controller annotation.

Comment: @ArtemBilan : The param1 is constant but the param2 is a XML.

Comment: @akhil I added an answer, as I think the Controller isn't inherited. I recommend you test your assumption (inheritance works with controller annotation) with a simple example that works when parent and child have controller, and then works/doesn't work when child class doesn't have controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subclass isn't marked as a @Controller and therefor Spring (when it scans for controllers) doesn't find it.

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745798/why-java-classes-do-not-inherit-annotations-from-implemented-interfaces)

Basically, annotations aren't inherited by default. 
You can use an annotation in the declaration of an annotation  to mark it as inherited [as is shown here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html)
by using:

```
public @interface Inherited
```

but if you look at [the controller source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.context/3.2.2/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.java), this keyword is not used in the Controller implementation spring uses.

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface Controller {
```

So I would assume @Controller is not inherited in your situation. I would first try out the inheritance with a simple example (class A extends class B , with just a simple unadorned method) to verify this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, the problem was My child class was not marked with Controller annotations, marking it with controller got me through this issue.