# Different media type for interface and implementation

Tags: java, rest

I have below code INTERFACE consuming application xml

```
@Path("/user")
public interface UserService {
@CONSUMES(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @POST
    @Path("/{userId}")
    public Response creaTeUser(@PathParam("userId") Long userId);

}
 I have implementation which consume application JSON

class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Override
    @POST
    @Path("/{userId}")
@CONSUMES(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUser(@PathParam("userId") Long userId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

when i do post user what will be actual media type

Answer (score 0):

Java method annotations do not support inheritance, so your media type would be `application/json`. See this answer: [Why java classes do not inherit annotations from implemented interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745798/why-java-classes-do-not-inherit-annotations-from-implemented-interfaces)