# How can we make interface annotations be inherited by implementations?

Tags: java, interface, annotations

When I have an Interface, for example:

```
public interface Model {

    String toString();

}
```

And I want that every class that implements this Interface will use the following Annotations:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```

So it will look like this in the Interface:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public interface Model {

    String toString();

}
```

And a test class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class User implements Model {

}
```

Something like this example doesn't work. How can I perform that, an abstract class with the annotations is maybe the solution?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. There is NO obligation in Java that annotation must be set  (if I understand, maybe no) 2. "not work" ... with which the message? 3. Annotationi, I have read somewhere, are not derived from parent.

Comment: @JacekCz I think the OP means that he wants implementations of that interface to automatically inherit those annotations, so "not work" means that those annotations didn't get inherited.

Comment: First shot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745798/why-java-classes-do-not-inherit-annotations-from-implemented-interfaces?rq=1 (and few others)

Comment: The [Unofficial JAXB Guide](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html) has a writeup on this subject with some recommendations.

Comment: @JacekCZ I updated my question with what I want to achive!

Answer (score 2):

A class never inherits annotations from the interfaces it implements.  Annotations that are so designated can be inherited from superclasses, but that's a characteristic of the annotation, and not the default.  If the annotations you are trying to use happen to be inheritable in that way -- you'll have to check their documentation -- then you can cause them to be inherited by deriving all your model classes from a common, annotated, superclass.

Really, though, what's so bad about annotating each class explicitly?  It's clearer, and no more verbose than implementing an interface.