# SuppressWarnings for sub class

Tags: java, eclipse, suppress-warnings

I have the following class which extends JFrame

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class View extends JFrame{
   //bla bla bla bla code
}
```

Now I have the following sub class:

```
public class Foo extends View{

   //bla bla bla bla
}
```

In the  `View`  class Eclipse is giving me a warning so I added SuppressWarnings to get rid of it.I thought that by doing this I wouldn't have to retype SuppressWarnings in the Foo class but as it seems eclipse is giving me a warning on Foo class.Should this be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*@SuppressWarnings* is an example of an annotation in Java. What you want is to let Foo inherit the annotations of View.

However, that's not possible in Java. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745798/why-java-classes-do-not-inherit-annotations-from-implemented-interfaces) question is describing why it's not possible (namely because otherwise multiple-inheritance could occur as interface methods can have annotations as well.

When Eclipse is giving you a warning you should not ignore it generally. Try to make Eclipse happy because it only warns you if it has a very good reason to do so. If you're really confident that in your program a SuppressWarnings is suitable, then all subclasses must use that same annotation as well.

Answer (score 1):

JFrame implements `Serializable` interface. For the class that implements `Serializable`, eclipse would ask it to have a serialVersionUID.

View extends from JFrame, we can say it also implements `Serializable` interface. So does `Foo`, and that's reason why you need to add serialVersionUID or add Suppress-Warning for both `View` and `Foo`.