# Can I use spring annotations on interfaces?

Tags: spring, annotations

I'm struggling with understanding spring framework. I use to work with Java EE.

When I write interfaces and implementations, Can I use annotation on interfaces?

```java
@Repository // Can I do this?
interface MyRepository {
}

@Repository // Can I omit this?
class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyRepository {
}
```

What about `@Service`? Is it same?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146391/annotations-on-interfaces .. This is pretty much the same question that you are asking

Comment: @ArunM [One of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/146422/330457) is what I wanted to know. Not the question, I think.

Comment: [Where to put @Transactional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551541/where-to-put-transactional-in-interface-specification-or-implementation). I second @Bozho answer

Answer (score 0):

According to Annotation definition we can use annotate interfaces. When we define a interface if that interface defined as `@Target({ java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE })` ,

then `TYPE` can  be `Class, interface (including annotation type), or enum declaration TYPE` according to [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#TYPE).

,