# Annotation on interface in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My interface:

```java
package com.demo.dependency;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "#{'${api.baseUrl}'}")
public interface BaseController<Response> {

    @PostMapping(value = "#{'${api.interface}'}")
    @ResponseBody
    public Response process(@RequestBody @Valid Request request) throws Exception;

}
```

Implementation:

```java
package com.demo.application;

public class BarController implements BaseController<BarResponse> {

    @Override
    public BarResponse process(Request request) throws Exception {
        // do something
    }

}
```

I'm new to Spring Boot. I wonder whether these annotations can work properly in implementation class:

- @RestController and @RequestMapping on interface class
- @PostMapping and @ResponseBody on interface method
- @RequestBody and @Valid on method parameters
- `#{'${api.baseUrl}'}` and `#{'${api.interface}'}` to read configure from `application.properties`

My spring boot version is 2.2.6.

It seems that my `SpringApplication` from package `com.demo.application` failed to auto scan `BarController`. However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146391/annotations-on-interfaces) says that "the annotation should apply to all subclasses", including @Service. Is anything wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Annotations aren't inherited from interfaces to classes in java, so the `@RestController` needs to be on the implementation class. The `@RequestMapping` might work due to the annotation processing in Spring itself.

Comment: `#{'${api.baseUrl}'}` and `#{'${api.interface}'}` will work. `@Valid` and `@RequestBody` will not work. Other are already answered by M. Deinum.